# Pandas: Count number of uppercase words

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count the number of uppercase words in a pandas dataframe.
I have a dataframe with a column in which there are lists of words in each cell.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can need first flatten values of lists with `DataFrame` constructor and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) or [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Then for separate word is necessary [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and `stack`, last check words by [`isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html) and count by `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['a','GA'],['SA dsdf fds We','Da','ddb D']]})
print (df)
                             A
0                      [a, GA]
1  [SA dsdf fds We, Da, ddb D]

b = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist())
      .stack()
      .str.split(expand=True)
      .stack()
      .str.isupper()
      .sum()
print (b)
3
```

Or:

```
b = pd.Series(np.concatenate(df['A'])).str.split(expand=True).stack().str.isupper().sum()
print (b)
3
```